# Set the value of a PHP Variable equal to the value of a HTML Element

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a PHP code that checks the status of a server.
The code works perfectly when it's used like this:

```
<?php
$SERVER_IP = "217.198.136.31";
$SERVER_PORT = "25565";
$QUERY_PORT = "25565";
?>
```

However, instead of manually assigning the values for the php variables I need to get them from two HTML input elements. I've tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<input id="checkip" name="checkip" value="217.198.136.31">
<input id="checkport" name="checkport" value="25565">

<?php
$SERVER_IP = $_POST['checkip'];
$SERVER_PORT = $_POST['checkport'];
$QUERY_PORT = $_POST['checkport'];
?>
```

I can't figure out why it isn't working, doesn't the $_POST get the exact value from the HTML elements and put them in the PHP variables? What should I do to get the same result for the last code?

Comment: Are you sending a POST request?

Comment: wrap inside a form and submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` reads data that has been submitted in the request. The values of your inputs will not be available there until after the page has been sent to the browser and a new page has been requested by the submission of a form (with `method="post"`) or some other technique to make an HTTP request (e.g. Ajax) has been used.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$SERVER_IP = $_POST['checkip'];
$SERVER_PORT = $_POST['checkport'];
echo "server ip is:" .$SERVER_IP;
 }

  ?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input id="checkip" name="checkip" value="217.198.136.31">
<input id="checkport" name="checkport" value="25565">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="checkip" name="checkip" value="217.198.136.31">
```

is a html-input-element belonging to a FORM, when this form is beeing sent, the target gets the form-fields and these are accessible by $_POST ... but only if the method of the form is POST

example:

```
<html>
<Body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])) echo $_POST['test'];
?>
<form action='?' method='post'>
<Input Name='test' value='123'>
<button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Keep in mind, that php is executed on Server, BEFORE Any form element gets evaluated by the Clients browser

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your not passing the value, the input type field must used inside a form example:

```
<form method=POST>
 <input id="checkip" name="checkip" value="217.198.136.31">
<input id="checkport" name="checkport" value="25565">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are actually posting your form.

`$_POST` will get values only if the form is posted with `method="post"`.

Otherwise, your code seems fine.

Hope it works.